# How can i estimate kinitic parameter of a steady-state reactor

Tags: matlab, optimization, model, curve-fitting, ode

I want to solve a system of ODE with some unknown parameters`k1,k2,k3`:

```
dC1/dx=-k1*C1
dC2/dx=k1*C1-k2*C2
dC3/dx=k2*C2-k3*C3
```

And I have a set of experimental results, with values of `C1,C2,C3` at `x=0` (inlet point) and `x=1` (end point).

I don't have any data in in between `x=0` and `x=1` to solve it with an ODE function like `ode45()` or `ode23()` and then use an optimization function. How can I solve this problem in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the boundary-value solver `bvp4c` (or `bvp5c`). The number of boundary conditions that can be satisfied is the sum of dimension of the ODE and number of unknown parameters, thus 6 possible conditions for the 6 known values that you want the parameters fixed to. That is, the functions to pass to the solver are

```
function dCdx = odesys(x,C,k)
    dCdx = zeros_like(C)
    dCdx(1) = -k(1)*C(1)
    dCdx(2) =  k(1)*C(1)-k(2)*C(2)
    dCdx(3) =  k(2)*C(2)-k(3)*C(3)

function bc = boundary(C0, CT, k)
    bc = [ C0(1)-c01, C0(2)-c02, C0(3)-c03, CT(1)-cT1, CT(2)-cT2, CT(3)-cT3 ]
```

As the initial guess you can use for instance some linear interpolation between the known values.

---

Regarding the modified system with provided boundary values

```
dC1/dx=-k1*C1/(1+k1*C1) ; 
dC2/dx=k1*C1/(1+k1*C1)-k2*C2 ; 
dC3/dx=k2*C2-k3*C3 ;
```

[image]

using the similar python solver with the script (but changing `x1` to `100`)

```
c0A, c0B, c0C = 293.3 , 2.1414, 3.6884
c1A, c1B, c1C = 208.09, 33.823, 78.561 
x0, x1 = 0.0, 100.0

def odesys(x,C,k):
    dCdx = zeros_like(C)
    dCdx[0] = -k[0]*C[0]/(1+k[0]*C[0]) ;
    dCdx[1] =  k[0]*C[0]/(1+k[0]*C[0])-k[1]*C[1]
    dCdx[2] =  k[1]*C[1]-k[2]*C[2]
    return dCdx

def bc(C0, C1, k):
    return [ C0[0]-c0A, C0[1]-c0B, C0[2]-c0C, C1[0]-c1A, C1[1]-c1B, C1[2]-c1C ]

x_init = linspace(x0,x1,21)
s = (x_init-x0)/(x1-x0)
C_init = [ c0A+s*(c1A-c0A), c0B+s*(c1B-c0B), c0C+s*(c1C-c0C)]

k = [1.0e-2, 1.0, 1.0]

res = solve_bvp(odesys, bc, x_init, C_init, k)
print res.message, res.p
```

It prints the results for the paramters `[ k1, k2, k3]` as

```
The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy. 
[ 0.02319266  0.02248122 -0.00678455]
```

That the third parameter is unphysically  negative hints that the model or some of the parameters are not correct. Additionally, plot the solution:

```
x_sol=np.linspace(x0,x1,301)    
C_sol=res.sol(x_sol)
for k in range(3): plt.subplot(1,3,k+1); plt.plot(x_sol, C_sol[k]); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

seems to show the correct behavior. Forward integration using these parameters with another integration method confirms the correctness of the solution

```
C_int = odeint( lambda C,t: odesys(t,C,res.p), res.sol(0), x_sol)
for k in range(3): plt.subplot(1,3,k+1); plt.plot(x_sol, C_int[:,k]); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i am trying to apply your method in matlab. can this mehod used for nonlinear diferential equation? for example if we had dCdx=-k1*C1/(1+k1*c1) instead of dCdx=-k1*c1 this function can be applyed or not???

Comment: The data are incompatible with this equation. The slope of C1 is bounded to (-1,0] which over the interval [0,1] makes a decrease of less than 1. The decrease of more than 85 is not possible. It might work if the interval went to 100.

Comment: i don't know python. how can i convert this code into matlab script??

Comment: these are the experimental data, it should be correct. i  want to find a pasitive value for kinitic parameters.if the values become negaive, it doesn't make any sense. we have to consider a posetive constrain for parameters to obtain the real values

Comment: As I said, then the model is too rigid or incomplete. But to discuss this you would need to give more input on what the model is about. One could also make a more general fitness function that takes the parameters `k` and returns the sum of the distances of the endpoints to the given endpoints. That you can then call with a general optimization solver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system of 3 ordinary differential equations problem. The values of `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` at `x=0` and `x=1` are initial conditions. You can solve it analytically by using `dsolve`. In my example, I assume the initial conditions are `C1(0)=1; C2(0)=1; C3(1)=1;`. You can modify them according to your data.

```
syms C1(x) C2(x) C3(x) k1 k2 k3

% Define the equations using == and represent differentiation using the diff function.
ode1 = diff(C1) == -k1*C1;
ode2 = diff(C2) == k1*C1-k2*C2;
ode3 = diff(C3) == k2*C2-k3*C3;
odes = [ode1; ode2; ode3]

% Define the initial conditions using ==
cond1 = C1(0) == 1;
cond2 = C2(0) == 1;
cond3 = C3(1) == 1;
conds = [cond1; cond2; cond3];

% dsolve function finds values for the constants that satisfy these conditions.
[C1Sol(x) C2Sol(x) C3Sol(x)] = dsolve(odes, conds)
```

Output

```
odes(x) =

           D(C1)(x) == -k1*C1(x)
 D(C2)(x) == k1*C1(x) - k2*C2(x)
 D(C3)(x) == k2*C2(x) - k3*C3(x)


C1Sol(x) =

exp(-k1*x)


C2Sol(x) =

-(exp(-k1*x)*exp(-k2*x)*((k1^2*k2*exp(k2*x))/((k1 - k2)*(k1 - k3)) - (k2^2*exp(k1*x)*(2*k1 - k2))/((k1 - k2)*(k2 - k3)) - (k1*k2*k3*exp(k2*x))/((k1 - k2)*(k1 - k3)) + (k2*k3*exp(k1*x)*(2*k1 - k2))/((k1 - k2)*(k2 - k3))))/k2


C3Sol(x) =

-exp(-k1*x)*exp(-k2*x)*exp(-k3*x)*((k2*exp(k1*x)*exp(k3*x)*(2*k1 - k2))/((k1 - k2)*(k2 - k3)) - (k1*k2*exp(k2*x)*exp(k3*x))/((k1 - k2)*(k1 - k3)) + (exp(k1*x)*exp(k2*x)*exp(k3)*(k1*k2^2 - k1^2*k2 - k1*k3^2 + k1^2*k3 + k2*k3^2 - k2^2*k3 + k1*k2^2*exp(-k1) + k1*k2^2*exp(-k2) - 2*k1^2*k2*exp(-k2) - k2^2*k3*exp(-k2) - k1*k2*k3*exp(-k1) + 2*k1*k2*k3*exp(-k2)))/((k1 - k2)*(k1 - k3)*(k2 - k3)))
```

Comment: i really thank you for your help. firstly, i have 4 data for each compound at inlet and outlet not only one. this is applicable just for one experiment. secondly, i need a numerical solution, because my equation will have a more parameters (here i just put 3 unknown.